# Choose my method name for delegate without reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

My delegate...

```
private delegate double CalculateDelegate(double x, double y);
```

Code for declareing delegate...

```
private CalculateDelegate calculate;
```

My methods for use in with my delegates...

```
private double Add(double x, double y) { return x + y; }
private double Subtract(double x, double y) { return x - y; }
```

How I execute the desired method...

```
calculate = new CalculateDelegate(Add);
```

or...

```
calculate = new CalculateDelegate(Subtract);
```

This works but as the actual code contains many more 'functions' I would like to avoid using a switch/IF statement. So all I need is to write the new method send it in.

The calc method (I usied that action here thinking it might work, it does not)

```
   public double calc(Action methodName, double x, double y)
    {
        calculate = new CalculateDelegate(methodName);
 return calculate(x,y);

    }
```

How I would like execute the desired method.

```
 public void go()
{
   calc(Add, 5,4);
}
```

Is this possible without reflection?

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking. Please describe more about actual problem and give a real and simple example about your requirement.

Comment: Based on what criteria are you supposed to pick the desired method?

Comment: You can just do: `CalculateDelegate method = Add;` - isn't that what you want? And `new CalculateDelegate(X)` - X is not just a "method name", it is an actual method, this is what is known as a "method group conversion". You have to supply *an actual method*, not just a name. But it isn't clear why you can't simply use the example I gave at the start of this comment.

Comment: The operative word is "choose".  There is more than one way to make a choice in a program.  Like the if and switch statements, the most straight-forward way to do it.  Or a lookup table, could be `Dictionary<Token, CalculationDelegate>`.  You'll have to pick one yourself.

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/17Y7qP), just use dictionary of your delegates with keys that equal names of delegates, look at example.:

```
public delegate double CalculateDelegate(double x, double y);

public class Test
{        
    public CalculateDelegate calculate;                
}

public class DelegateContainer
{
    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    public double Subtract(double x, double y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, CalculateDelegate> collection = new Dictionary<string, CalculateDelegate>();
    public DelegateContainer()
    {
        collection["Add"] = Add;
        collection["Subtract"] = Subtract;
    }

    public CalculateDelegate this[string name]
    {            
        get
        {                
            return collection[name];
        }            
    }
}

public static void Main()
{        
    var target = new Test();
    var container = new DelegateContainer();
    target.calculate = container["Add"];
    Console.WriteLine("1 + 2 = " + target.calculate(1, 2));

    target.calculate = container["Subtract"];
    Console.WriteLine("5 - 2 = " + target.calculate(5, 2));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the delegate manually, the type is inferred automatically; i.e. simply `collection["Add"] = Add;` would work.

Comment: Thanks to @LousyCoder.

Comment: This is what I also guess the OP needs.

Comment: thanks I am going in to a meeting in a mo but will try this out shortly.